# Why isn't my furnace starting?

Tags: hvac

We have a Consolidated Industries All Purpose upflow furnace which is not kicking on. We have replaced circuit boards, capacitor and the inducer motor. We also put a new thermostat in. It works fine when running and is very quiet.

After we replaced the thermostat and capacitor, it ran perfectle for about a week, then it kicked off and will not kick back on unless we power it off and back on.

The thermostat still showed heat on.

Comment: "Kicking on" isn't a a good technical description. Does the inducer fan run? Does the gas valve click open? Does the igniter operate? Does the burner light? Does your control board have error codes showing? What's the actual model? Please revise and be more specific.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include all the details asked for by @isherwood, above, and any and every other detail you can think of - the more detail the better.

Comment: What model is said furnace, and can you post its wiring diagram?

Comment: I hope you saved all those parts it is probably a flow/pressure sensor, there should be an error code on the board. When you open the panel the power goes out? Look for a plunger switch these can normally be pulled out to allow troubleshooting, just remember that the electrical is live. My bet is that the pressure/flow safety switch is going bad as a safety it takes a power cycle to clear it. It could be other safety’s but you said it operated normally after a power cycle.